# Keeps saying error 105

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write q query  for my sql sever for a database where i retrieve the HotelID's and names of all Hotels in Melbourne that have King size beds but it comes up with HotelID in field list is ambiguous i dont know how to solve this? this is my query

```
SELECT      City, BedTypeDesc, HotelName, HotelID 
FROM     BedTypes,     Hotels,     Cities,     Rooms 
WHERE     Hotels.CityID = Cities.CityID         AND Hotels.HotelID = Rooms.HotelID          AND Rooms.BedTypeID = BedTypes.BedTypeID         AND BedTypeDesc = 'King Size'         AND City = 'Melbourne'
```

Comment: Error 105 means that you can only create a foreign key on one table that references a key on another table.

Comment: Use `hotels.HotelId` -- your query doesn't know which table to use it from.  Also consider using the more standard `join` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You should use table aliases an proper `join` syntax:

```
SELECT c.City, bt.BedTypeDesc, h.HotelName, h.HotelID 
FROM Hotels h JOIN
     Cities c
     ON h.CityID = c.CityID JOIN
     Rooms r
     ON h.HotelID = r.HotelID JOIN
     BedTypes bt
     ON r.BedTypeID = bt.BedTypeID         
WHERE bt.TypeDesc = 'King Size' AND c.City = 'Melbourne' ;
```

Comment: Thank you i'd just about givin up on it.